# PyCharm / Python docstring return type hint for locally imported class

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to define a rtype in the docstring, using a class which is not imported globally in the module (because I cannot do that, because of circular imports).

I.e. like this:

```
def get_engine():
   """
   :rtype: sisyphus.localengine.LocalEngine
   """
   from sisyphus.localengine import LocalEngine
   return LocalEngine()
```

`sisyphus` is a package, and `sisyphus.localengine` a module in that package. I registered the parent directory of `sisyphus` as the source root directory in PyCharm.

This does not seem to work. At least PyCharm (2018.2.4) shows the type hint `() -> Any` for this function.

If I remove the `rtype` hint, it shows the correct hint `() -> LocalEngine`, so the audio-detection works (if I don't want to explicitly specify it).

How do I correctly specify the `rtype` hint such that this works?

Comment: Is pycharm auto detecting the type returned by that function/method?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in python >=3.5, you can use [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) in type hinting.
See also this jetbrains [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/).

```py
def foo() -> 'sisyphus.localengine.LocalEngine':
    ...
```

Comment: Hm, so PyCharm marks this with an error (Cannot find reference `localengine` in imported module `sisyphus`.)

Comment: Also, any way for Python 2 as well?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not import a module within a function.  If you move the import to the top of the file does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be done in 2.x, forward references were added in 3.5.

Comment: It cannot be moved out of the function because of circular dependencies.